# Error Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined javascript

Tags: javascript, web

Tengo una aplicación con JavaScript que me da este error si intento usar una librería de encriptación llamada Rijnsdael-js. Este es el código, el error se produce cuando hago el Require()

```
private funcion(cadena){
 let mode = "CFP";
 let pass = "password";
 let iv = 'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis no';

 const mycrypt = require('js-rijndael');

 var encryptedMessage = mycrypt.encrypt(cadena, iv, pass, "rijndael-256", mode);

 return encryptedMessage;
}
```

¿Por qué se produce esto y cómo podría solucionarlo? Gracias.

Comment: Necesitaríamos conocer algunos detalles más de tu entorno (Node JS me imagino) ¿puedes enseñarnos un poco más la estructura de tu directorio?, o al menos mostrar la salida exacta del error que recibes, que me imagino que probablemente es porque no encuentra el módulo. El `return` que tienes ahí suelto no tiene mucho sentido .....

Comment: Si estás intentando ejecutar este código en el lado cliente (navegador) entonces el problema es ese. El patrón de módulos CommonJS que usa Node no se puede usar directamente en el navegador, es por ello que te da el error que expones. Para que tu código funcione en el navegador has de empaquetarlo para ese propósito, usando alguna librería como `webpack` o `browserfy`. Saludos

Comment: He editado el código para que sea más entendible. El error no me da más información, solo me sale eso. Por otro lado, he instalado browserify, lo he ejecutado y me genera un archivo completamente vacío, no lo entiendo.

Comment: Con browserify me da el siguiente error: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'